# crazy things with PHP array

Tags: php

A very strange thing, I have an array where element 7 is `'[1000137d]'`, but when I try to compare it by using `if ( $array[7] == '[1000137d]' )` it will return a negative.

```
echo $array[7];
echo '<br>';
echo '[1000137d]';
echo '<br>';
echo md5($array[7]);
echo '<br>';
echo md5('[1000137d]');
```

this code would echo out:

```
[1000137d]
[1000137d]
ca9983334e720042e3a6cbb1dd6b7fd2
3b1c21e661bd7d38deda1f4a45eaa23b
```

as you can see `$array[7]` is identical to `[1000137d]`, yet their md5's differ. what do you think might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: try `var_dump($array[7]);` and `var_dump('[1000137d]');`...  It will give you both value and type (to see why it may be different)...

Comment: aha, string(12) " [1000137d]" string(10) "[1000137d]" . YES! I trimmed off the spaces and now it works! Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some trailing whitespace, to give one example, that gives no apparent difference.  Try `var_dump($array[7])` to see if that outputs the expected `string(10) "[1000137d]"`.

Edit: wow I'm slow (in more ways than one ;)

Comment: aha, string(12) " [1000137d]" string(10) "[1000137d]" . YES! I trimmed off the spaces and now it works! Thanks man!

Comment: @user296516: You can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it as the correct answer.